# SignalR Start()'s task is continuing even if connection is not possible

Tags: signalr

I have a C# SignalR client and I want to do some actions upon success/failure of the connection to my server. Here is my code :

```cs
this.connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
{
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            this.OnRaiseServerConnectionClosedEvent();
        }
        else
        {
            this.JoinGroup();
            this.StopTimer();
            this.OnRaiseServerConnectionOpenedEvent();
         }
    });
}
```

The else block is always executed, not caring if a server is here or not...

I have also tried with await or with `Wait()` but same scenario.

I understand .net tasks correctly I think but here I am stuck.

---

Right now my code looks like

```cs
try
{
    this.connection.Start().Wait();
    if (this.connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        this.JoinGroup();
        this.StopTimer();
        this.OnRaiseServerConnectionOpenedEvent();
    }
 }
 catch (AggregateException)
 {
    this.OnRaiseServerConnectionClosedEvent();
 }
 catch (InvalidOperationException)
 {
    this.OnRaiseServerConnectionClosedEvent();
 }
```

When no server is present, the task created by the Start() method returns without fault and with status connecting. You have to check the state of the connection if you want to follow with some actions or retry connecting.

Comment: What versions of the SignalR server and .Net client are you running?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it. Server and client are in v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The task you are receiving from Connection.Start is likely cancelled due to a timeout instead of being faulted. This should be an easy fix:

```cs
this.connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
    {
        this.OnRaiseServerConnectionClosedEvent();
    }
    else
    {
        this.JoinGroup();
        this.StopTimer();
        this.OnRaiseServerConnectionOpenedEvent();
     }
});
```

If you use Wait() instead of ContinueWith, an AggregateException containing an OperationCanceledException in its InnerExceptions collection will be thrown when the task is canceled.

Comment: Adding "task.IsCanceled" does not fix it, the else block is still executed even when my server is down. Using Wait() I effectivelly got the AggregateException but I also get an InvalidOperationException due to the Invoke in the JoinGroup() method.